# geoLocation and googleMaps flutter

Tags: flutter, geolocation

```
Future<Position> getLocation() async {
  Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
  return position;
}

class trip extends StatefulWidget {
  const trip({super.key});

  @override
  State<trip> createState() => tripState();
}
  static const CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(33.8869, 9.5375),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );
```

I want to use the lat and long inside the CameraPosition's target: LatLng(lat,long)
Everytime I put it the compiler signs that there is an issue in the code

I've tryed making the type double but same problem, I can't